# Automatically close webform after submission

Tags: webforms, javascript, chaos-tool-suite

I have created a [Webform](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwj9m5ny-9LHAhVHS44KHfmPDh0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Fwebform&ei=_BjkVf2tLMeWuQT5n7roAQ&usg=AFQjCNEYNUc259b4FDfzvTnFmZwwO38a8A&sig2=WpzO_Dq4ckA6RgVljiovMQ) with some terms & condition. I have added this webform in **node/upload** page. When user access node/upload page webform comes as overlay on the page. When user selects all terms & condition and submits it redirects to another page which as **close** link. When close link is clicked webform hides.

What I want is instead clicking on **close** link to hide the webform. When user submits the terms & conditions the webform must be hidden. How can i achieve this. I have added screen shot of webforms. 
[image]

[image]

I have added this code to get the webform in node/upload page

```
 if (!isset($user->data['guided'])) {
  $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/js/my_module_ajax.js';
}
ctools_include('modal');
ctools_modal_add_js();
if (!isset($user->data['guided'])) {
$form['guideline'] = array(
  '#markup' => '<p>' . t('Review and follow the guidelines outlined in the <a href="@guideline-page" class="ctools-use-modal">Submission guidelines</a> before uploading an item.', array('@guideline-page' => url('modal_forms/nojs/webform/' . 31))) . '</p>',
  '#weight' => -0.01,
);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code mentioned in [#4](https://www.drupal.org/node/2077393#comment-8586091) should work.

```
  function my_module_form_id_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form["#submit"][] = "my_module_submit";
    if ( $form_state['submitted']){
      $commands[] = ctools_modal_command_dismiss();
       print ajax_render($commands);
       exit;
    }
    return $form;
 }

 function my_module_submit($form,&$form_state) {
   $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use hook_form_alter() and on submit of the form you need to set action like this

```
$form["#submit"][] = "ajax_modal_form_submit";
```

and add function

```
function ajax_modal_form_submit($form,&$form_state) {
    ctools_include('ajax');
    ctools_include('modal');    
    $form_state['ajax_commands'][] = ctools_modal_command_dismiss();
    $form_state['ajax_commands'][] = ctools_ajax_command_reload();
    drupal_set_message(t("You detail submitted successfully!"));
  }
```

Comment: I have tried but not working

Comment: check in log messages is there any error regarding this?